# how to create a dataframe from csv with a colon separator

Tags: python, pandas

I am parsing an Outlook message with the following code:

```
email_content = str(message.Body)
lines_stripped = [line.strip() for line in email_content.split('\r\n') if line.strip() != '']
for line in lines_stripped:
    writer = csv.writer(write_file, delimiter=" ")
    writer.writerow(line.split())
```

CSV file looks like this:

```
Car: Mazda

Color: Green

Comment: A very nice Car

Car: Toyota

Color: Black

Comment: Okay car
```

I want to transform this something like this:

```
Car     Color       Comment
Mazda   Green       A very nice Car
Toyota  Black       Okay car
```

Comment: That's not CSV at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do most of this in pure python, using this `split_at` pattern:

```
In [11]: def split_at(lst, f):
    ...:     inds = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if f(x)]
    ...:     for i, j in zip(inds, inds[1:]):
    ...:         yield lst[i:j]
    ...:     yield lst[j:]
    ...:
```

Which allows you to split the list of properties:

```
In [12]: cars = [c.split(": ", 1) for c in cars.splitlines() if c]

In [13]: cars
Out[13]:
[['Car', 'Mazda'],
 ['Color', 'Green'],
 ['Comment', 'A very nice Car'],
 ['Car', 'Toyota'],
 ['Color', 'Black'],
 ['Comment', 'Okay car']]

In [14]: pd.DataFrame([dict(c) for c in split_at(cars, lambda x: x[0] == "Car")])
Out[14]:
      Car  Color          Comment
0   Mazda  Green  A very nice Car
1  Toyota  Black         Okay car
```

Comment: yield lst[j:] - local variable 'j' referenced before assignment. This is what I am encountering

Comment: @LearningNoob do you only have one block (one car?)

Comment: yup i have only one

Comment: @learningNoob In that case you don't need to split_at you can just use of `pd.DataFrame(dict(cars))`. I'll add a fix for this single iten case when I am back at a computer!

Answer (score 2):

```
##data

temp = StringIO("""  
Car: Mazda

Color: Green

Comment: A very nice Car

Car: Toyota

Color: Black

Comment: Okay car""")

df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep=':', engine='python', header=None)
df.columns = ['A','B']
```

---

```
##print(df)

         A                 B
0      Car             Mazda
1    Color             Green
2  Comment   A very nice Car
3      Car            Toyota
4    Color             Black
5  Comment          Okay car
```

using `pd.pivot` and using `sorted` with key as null

```
pd.pivot(index=df.index, columns=df.A, values=df.B).apply(sorted,key=pd.isnull).dropna()
```

**Output**

```
A      Car   Color           Comment
0    Mazda   Green   A very nice Car
1   Toyota   Black          Okay car
```

Comment: `TypeError: pivot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

Comment: were you using pivot_table func..because pd.pivot doesn't require data arg @Poudel

Comment: strange, not getting the same. also doc doesn't specify additional args @Poudel

Comment: @iamklaus apologize if I didn't include this on my problem, but this will fail when there is something like this: Time: 7/18/2019 01:10:27. This due to the timestamp. Any workaround?

Comment: its all about reading the data to the df, so for that update sep=': ' for the new data.@LearningNoob

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = '''
Car: Mazda

Color: Green

Comment: A very nice Car

Car: Toyota

Color: Black

Comment: Okay car

'''
input_csv = io.StringIO(temp)
#input_csv = 'hello.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_csv, sep=":", skip_blank_lines=True,header=None)
data = np.array_split(df[1].to_numpy(), len(df)/3)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df[0].unique())
print(df2)

       Car   Color           Comment
0    Mazda   Green   A very nice Car
1   Toyota   Black          Okay car
```

Using pure python + pandas

```py
cars = []
colors = []
comments = []

lines = io.StringIO(temp).readlines()
for line in lines:
  if line.startswith('Car'):
    cars.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())
  if line.startswith('Color'):
    colors.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())
  if line.startswith('Comment'):
    comments.append(line.split(':')[1].strip())

df = pd.DataFrame({'car': cars, 'color': colors, 'comment': comments})
df
```